# Why is there a gallery with my fancybox

Tags: jquery

[image: additional navigation button]

I have used the fancybox script to call a HTML block but what I don't get is its showing a gallery with the navigation buttonwhen my link only points to 1 HTML block. When I click the next button, the same content shows up.

```
<a class="measurement" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('measurement') ?>" rel="iframeLink"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/sizeguide.gif')?>" />
```

### The Code I'm Using:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('lightboxes/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js'); ?>'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('lightboxes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js'); ?>'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('lightboxes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css'); ?>' media='screen'/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("a[rel=iframeLink]").fancybox({
'type' : 'iframe',
'width' : 600,
'height' : 500,
'scrolling'   : 'no'
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: provide the website link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use class .measurement instead of a[rel=iframeLink]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".measurement ").fancybox({
    'type' : 'iframe',
     'width' : 600,
     'height' : 500,
      'scrolling'   : 'no'
      });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: try to remove the attribute (rel) from your <a></a> right now if no thing changed i will do demo for You